# PHP form validation using GUMP

Tags: php, validation, redirect

I'm using GUMP https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP for server side form validation and have a question regarding showing messages after a redirect.

I want to validate the form data after submission, then redirect to the form if there was an error but I don't know the best way to pass the errors to the form after the redirect.

I've read this question [Header Redirect after form Validation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214553/header-redirect-after-form-validation-in-php) which suggests two ways of doing this:

1.

```
$message="Some message for the next page.";
$message=urlencode($message);
header("Location:page.php?message=".$message);
```

2.

```
$_SESSION['message']='some other message';
```

The author of the answer thinks method 1 is more secure, but can you tell me why that would be?

I've also had a look at how it's done by php-form-builder class https://github.com/lkorth/php-form-builder-class, and they seem to use method 2:

```
/*Valldation errors are saved in the session after the form submission, and will be displayed to the user
when redirected back to the form.*/
public static function setError($id, $errors, $element = "") {
    if(!is_array($errors))
        $errors = array($errors);
    if(empty($_SESSION["pfbc"][$id]["errors"][$element]))
        $_SESSION["pfbc"][$id]["errors"][$element] = array();
    foreach($errors as $error)
        $_SESSION["pfbc"][$id]["errors"][$element][] = $error;
}
```

So, my question is, which is the best way to go about this? Pass the errors with `$_GET` or in session variables?

p.s. If I've missed something, and there is a way to do it that's easier/built into GUMP, please point it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two files, one of them contains all the PHP business logic and the other the form (which you include in the first file). The first file does two things: it checks to see if the form was submitted and displays the form. On the first run, there are no error messages because the form has yet to be submitted. If the form is submitted and it does not validate, have the form display the error message(s) (i.e.; `<?php echo $gump->get_readable_errors(true) ?>`). No need to store the error messages in session. You could also re-populate the form with the previously submitted data.

form.php

```
<?php
$_error_messages = '';
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) :
    $gump = new GUMP();
    // Let's sanitize the POST data
    $_POST = $gump->sanitize($_POST);
    $gump->validation_rules(array(
         // your validationm rules here
    ));
    $gump->filter_rules(array(
         // your filter rules here
    ));
    // Validate the form data
    $validated_data = $gump->run($_POST);
    if ($validated_data === false) :
        // The submitted data did not validate,
        // display the errors in the form
        $_error_messages = $gump->get_readable_errors(true);
    else :
        // The submitted data validated successfully
        . . .
    endif;
endif;
// Display your form
include 'form-view.php';
```

form-view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        // . . .
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <?php echo $_error_messages ?>
            <form
                action = '<?php echo htmlentities('form.php'); ?>'
                method = 'post'
                name   = 'my_form'
            >
                // The rest of your form here
            </form>
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```